# How can i insert a currency symbol in the jsf page with precision of 2 digits

Tags: jsf, tags

hi how can i insert a currency symbol in the jsf page with precision of 2 digits

i am using the following libs

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.ibm.com/jsf/html_extended" prefix="hx"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/oasis.tld" prefix="oasis"%>
```

but if i use the following libs :

```
<jsp:root xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" version="2.0"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:hx="http://www.ibm.com/jsf/html_extended"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:oasis="/WEB-INF/oasis.tld">
```

this tag is working

```
<f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2"/>
```

but if i use the first libs this tag is not working

can any one tell me how to insert a currency symbol and precision of 2 digits by using first libs

Comment: Could you rephrase your question, please? It seems that it missing some information.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try the `<f:convertNumber/>` [component](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/convertNumber.html)?

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.myAmount}">
    <f:convertNumber minFractionDigits="2" maxFractionDigits="2" currencySymbol="XXX"/>
</h:outputText>
```

(where XXX is your currency symbol)

Comment: Ok, I posted this before editing your question, so maybe it is not what you are looking for...